# What is jellium aromaticity?

Tags: aromaticity

As I understand, if a molecule is cyclic and planar, then every atom in the ring must be $\ce{sp^2}$-hybridized and the molecule must have [4n+2] π electrons, where n∈N (Hückel’s rule).

An [article](https://www.chemistryworld.com/news/new-rule-predicts-stabilising-aromaticity-in-open-shell-metal-clusters/3010515.article) in Chemistry World by Sam Howell ("New rule predicts stabilising aromaticity in open-shell metal clusters", 21 MAY 2019), talks about jellium aromaticity.

[image]

image source : https://www.chemistryworld.com/news/new-rule-predicts-stabilising-aromaticity-in-open-shell-metal-clusters/3010515.article

My  question is what is jellium aromaticity?

Does it have anything to do with Hückel's rule?

Comment: Helpful: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/30997449

Comment: @user79161 this link leads to abstract and a paywall.Further it talks about spherical aromaticity. Now that

Comment: @user79161 Sperical aromaticity ??? That will wartent a seperate question.

Comment: I can't help with the paywall in any legal way, I'm afraid. Secondly, it pertains to jellium aromaticity as analogy to **spherical** one, as you noted. Thirdly, I regret you didn't find it helpful.

Comment: **I didn't mean they're analogous.** The paper deals with them in that way. I suppose we can get to an answer if we try to understand what we are typing here, for starters. Besides, how much information do you expect out of a 3-page paper. The link says helpful, not answer.

Comment: As a comment I can say that aromaticity is used to mean an extra stability. For starting refer to Hirsch aromaticity in Wikipedia

Comment: Please note that atoms cannot be hybridised in the sloppy way it is said "sp²-hybridised atom"; this usually implies that an atom has sp² orbitals, or is trigonally coordinated. In any case, the continuous loop of orbitals is more important. Also, while all Hückel aromats are aromatic, not all aromats obey Hückel's rules.