# How often is the IUPAC Goldbook Updated?

Tags: reference-request, books

I was wondering how often does the IUPAC update its Gold Book, ie, IUPAC Compendium of Chemical Terminology - the Gold Book.

It poped in my mind when I saw [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/115797/what-is-jellium-aromaticity) about jellium aromaticity, that the term should be there. However, it was not. Whereas, the term has been used several times in the linked references ([1](https://doi.org/10.1039/c9cc02067e) [2](https://doi.org/10.1021/jp804667d)), which I like to consider credible.

So, I was wondering how up-to-date the book is and how much can one rely on it for latest information.

PS While I understand that this question is primarily and heavily opinion based, I think it is equally relevant to all of us as we delve further in the chemical world.

Comment: It looks like Gold Book, the online edition, is a rolling release with corrections and additions done when they are done.

Comment: As for your suggestion to introduce `iupac` tag, currently it looks like there is no need for it: [Do we need the iupac tag?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3801/do-we-need-the-iupac-tag). If you disagree, feel free to discuss this matter on Meta. In fact, it's better to search or ask on Meta first whether tax $x$ or $y$ would be necessary beforehand.

Comment: And I don't think an iupac tag is needed. It wouldn't find much usage after a few questions, and there's no need to focus on a single organization as such. Anyway, more on this if it pops up on meta.

Comment: Oh, and, the Gold book is up-to-date, don't worry about that. **It is the book which decides what's up-to-date.**

Comment: @WilliamREBenzener, put it very well, it is IUPAC which decides what's up-to-date and not the other way round. So, does the question remains relevant, or should be closed, or deleted or left as it is?

Comment: There is a lot of terminology that probably never catches the attention of IUPAC because it is rarely used, or only in very special cases and by a small subset of chemists or physicists, especially if it is something new and in development. This is perhaps the case with jellium aromaticity. There is something called the jellium model, a model that's used in the solid-state materials field but might otherwise seem somewhat obscure to chemists. A search for this term should lead you to a world of hits.

Comment: see btw http://publications.iupac.org/pac-2007/1990/pdf/6201x0103.pdf

Comment: @user79161 Well it isn't a bad question - seeing that not many new users are familiar with stuff. If you have a good insight into the question already, you could [answer your own question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), or wait for a good answer and accept it.

Comment: IUPAC.org appears to have on line meeting minutes and activity reports of the various committees and sub-committees. It would also seem that work continues through the year. It would seem that updates occur as they come up and agreed upon, not a fixed times (as they used to do pre-web).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As various users have contributed to the arrival of this answer, it goes to the  community.

**Firstly**, the IUPAC is the authority of chemistry, which decides on and accepts terminology for international compatibility so that information can be unambiguously expressed by researchers, scholars, educators and students. So, it can be finally concluded that unless it is IUPAC approved, it is not official terminology.

**Secondly**, since the IUPAC is an enormous organisation, dealing at a global level, it can be understood that changes will be a little delayed as the information has to be checked for authenticity and a common end has to be reached. For example, it took quite some time to decide on the newcomers of the Periodic Table(Elements of Atomic Number 113-118).

**Thirdly**, a lot of terminology has a very limited scope and can be at the very least left out. For example, the `iupac` tag was dropped due to its limited scope.(See comments above).

Lastly, I thank the community for the comments which have fabricated the "bonds" of this answer.

Comment: I commend your efforts for this.